# linq expression for string array always results in "The name 'result' does not exist in the current context"

Tags: linq

I'm trying to get certain keys from the Request.Form.AllKeys string array by using the following:

```
var result = keys.Where(key => key.StartsWith("added"));
```

The result is "The name 'result' does not exist in the current context" no matter what I do.

I've also tried:

```
var result = (from keys in Request.Form.AllKeys
              where keys.StartsWith("added")
              select keys).ToArray();
```

Same thing.

I'm new to Linq and Lambda expressions and all, so please forgive the ignorance.

Regards,
Jacques

Comment: You haven't shown where you're trying to *use* `result`. Please give a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Hi Jon, that's exactly where the problem seems to come from. Being new to Linq I didn't realise that the object would only have any meaning once put to use. As soon as I added if(result.Any()) things suddenly jumped into action.

Comment: Well you still shouldn't have seen a compile-time error (which this sounds like) just by declaring a variable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question: Delayed execution.

When I actually executed the code and then followed it up by using result.Any() the expression was executed and turned out the correct results.

Comment: But the error you've suggested sounds like it was at *compile-time*. Or were you seeing it in the debugger? (This is where it's so important to be clear in your question...)